# Trying to get nav to toggle close after li item has been selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the menu to automatically animate closed after an item within the menu has been clicked on. And I want the user to still have the option to toggle the menu again. I managed to get the item to disappear after an item is clicked using `$('#overlay').toggleClass();` but now the user no longer has the option to click on the menu again. I've tried googling around but can't find a clear answer. I'm new to JavaScript can someone please point me in the right direction.

Link to example http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpRmgE

HTML

```
<div class="button_container" id="toggle">
  <span class="top"></span>
  <span class="middle"></span>
  <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay">
  <nav class="overlay-menu">
    <ul>
      <li ><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#portfolio">Port</a></li>
      <li><a href="#about">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>

<section id="home">
  <p>First</p>
</section>
<section id="portfolio">
  <p>Second</p>
</section>
<section id="about">
  <p>Third</p>
</section>
<section id="contact">
  <p>Fourth</p>
</section>
```

JavaScript

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
    $("nav li").click(function () {
        $('#overlay').toggleClass();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your example seems to work fine for me. I'm able to open and close the menu by clicking on the button and each of the buttons in the menu change the content outside of the menu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You weren't far off... just a few wrongly placed calls inside the click handler.

Try this:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
});
$("nav li").click(function() {
  $('#overlay').toggleClass('open');
  $('#toggle').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Forked [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXLVeE)

Comment: Beat me to it by 6 seconds :p

Comment: @mcon - I'll race you again if you can find a "race track" :-)

Comment: Also appreciate the help @mcon 

You guys are my heros!!

Comment: Bonus question.. how would I get to page to animate to the section? Link slide/glide up or down to that section?

Comment: It's better if you ask a different question for this - that's even in the [ask] "manual" :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way to make your event handler more clear:

```
$('#toggle').click(function() {
// Adding classes, waiting for a click
$(this).addClass('active');
$('#overlay').addClass('open');
$("nav li").click(function () {
    // Clicked! Removing classes
    $('#overlay').removeClass('open');
    $('#toggle').removeClass('active');
});
```

});
I personally usually use the addClass and removeClass functions when you are doing that kind of specific action. That helps you avoid small errors that could take long to be seen. :)